# Change margins of the first page of toc

Tags: table-of-contents

My university requires 2" margin for toc, and i'm pretty lost on how this should be done. Another problem is how the dots are displayed in TOC and list of tables, the problem is that the dot doesn't start immediately after the last letter. I include a part of my `uls` file and my thesis file.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, copyright,dissertation,]{usfmanus}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in]{geometry}
\pdfpagewidth=8.5in
\pdfpageheight=11in

% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhf{} 
% \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
% \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
%     \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{-1pt}%
%     \fancyhf{}%
%     \fancyfoot[R]{\hfill\thepage}%
% }

% \usepackage{tocbasic}
% \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
%   beforeskip=1em plus 1pt,% default is 1em plus 1pt
%   pagenumberformat=\textbf
% ]{tocline}{chapter}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,alltt,url,verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx,leftidx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc,automata,positioning,shadows}


\newrobustcmd*{\mysquare}[1]{\tikz{\filldraw[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0)
rectangle (0.2cm,0.2cm);}}

\newrobustcmd*{\mycircle}[1]{\tikz{\filldraw[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) circle [radius=0.1cm];}}

\newrobustcmd*{\mytriangle}[1]{\tikz{\filldraw[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) --
(0.2cm,0) -- (0.1cm,0.2cm);}}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 

%\usepackage{mybeamer}
% \setenumerate[0]{leftmargin=0.5in}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{color}

%YC: change algorithm's caption margin
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@algocf@capt@plain}{above}% formerly {bottom}
\makeatother


\let\oldnl\nl% Store \nl in \oldnl
\newcommand{\nonl}{\renewcommand{\nl}{\let\nl\oldnl}}% Remove line for one line
\newcommand{\eg}{\mbox{{\em e.g.}}}
\newcommand{\ie}{\mbox{{\em i.e.}}}
\newcommand{\viz}{\mbox{{\em viz.}}}
\newcommand{\rememberlines}{\xdef\rememberedlines{\number\value{AlgoLine}}}
\newcommand{\resumenumbering}{\setcounter{AlgoLine}{\rememberedlines}}
\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}



\newgeometry{top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in,includehead,includefoot,heightrounded}


\title{A Communication-Centric Framework for Post-Silicon System-on-chip Integration\\~ Debug}
\author{Yuting Cao}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy in Computer Science and Engineering} 
\department{Computer Science and Engineering} 
\college{Engineering} 
\majorprofessor{Hao Zheng, Ph.D.} 
\majorproftitle{Associate  Professor, Department of Computer Science and Engineering} 
\members{Srinivas Katkoori, Ph.D. 
    \and Swaroop Ghosh, Ph.D.
    \and Sanjukta Bhanja, Ph.D.
    \and Sandip Ray, Ph.D.} 
% \presentdate{October 30, 2019}
\presentdate{Feburary 16, 2018}
\keywords{validation, observability enhancement, debug infrastructure, trace analysis, specification mining}

\graddate{December, 2019} \copyrightyear{2019}

%\dedication{}

\acknowledgments{ 
\hspace{\parindent} 

xxx
}

\abstract{
\hspace{\parindent} 
xxx
}
% \makeatletter
% \renewcommand\@dotsep{1}% default is 4.5
% \makeatother

\begin{document}
% \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1pt}
% \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{2pt}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\input{1-intro}
\input{2-literature-review}
\input{figures/2-back}
\input{3}
\input{4-trace-analysis}
\input{5-CTM}
\input{5-signalselection}
\input{6-casestudy}
\input{5-mining}
\input{10-Conclusion.tex}




\begin{spacing}{1}
{\interlinepenalty=10000
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{soc}}
\end{spacing}
\clearpage

\input{appendix.tex}
%\end{appendix}


\end{document}
```

My TOC looks like this:
[image: my toc looks like this]

My list of tables looks like this:
[image: my list of tables looks like this]

My `uls` file looks like this:

```latex
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
  \tableofcontents
  \listoftables
  \listoffigures
  \@mylists
  %\abstracttitlepage
  \abstractpage}
```

Comment: my main file looks like this:

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange. Please provide a compiling [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that we can help you (we don't have files 1-intro.tex to 10-Conclusion.tex, nor the usfmanus.cls class file). For the margin, have a look to `\thispagestyle{}` command. For the dots, have a look to the [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package.